# Stuck in an infinite loop (LC3 Assembly language)

Tags: assembly, subroutine, lc3

I am currently working on an assignment in LC-3 assembly language. The assignment implements a program in LC3 assembly language that takes user input strings, echoes them back to the user, and then packs the strings. The program comes already completed, save for 2 subroutines that we're supposed to complete. I'm working out the Get String subroutine, and my code is stuck in an infinite loop, and I'm not sure why. If it's not too much trouble, could anyone take a look at my code, and see if they spot the problem? I think it has something to do with the branch I use the GETSTR subroutine, but I'm not sure. Here is my code so far.

```
enter code here .ORIG   x3000

LEA R0, PROMPT  ;Prompt for input
TRAP    x22

LD  R0, STRING  ;Input a character string
JSR GETSTR

LD  R0, NEWLIN  ;Start a new output line
TRAP    x21

LD  R0, STRING  ;Display the input string
TRAP    x22

JSR PAKSTR      ;Pack the character string

LD  R0, NEWLIN  ;Start a new output line
TRAP    x21

LD  R0, STRING
TRAP    x24     ;Display the packed string

LD  R0, NEWLIN
TRAP    x21

TRAP    x25     ;Halt
;Data

NEWLIN  .FILL   x0A

STRING  .FILL   x3100

PROMPT  .STRINGZ "Enter a character string, hit ENTER> "


;------------------------------------------------------------

GETSTR  ;Input a character string from the keyboard to memory
;Each input character is echoed at the console
;End of input is signalled by NEWLN (Enter key) x0A
;The end of the string in memory is marked by x0000
;Parameters -   R0 : address of the string


ST  R7, GET_7

JUMP    ADD R2, R0,0

ADD R2, R2, 1

TRAP    x20

BRnp    JUMP

TRAP    x21



LD  R7, GET_7

RET

GET_7   .BLKW   1


;---------------------------------------------------------------------

PAKSTR  ;Create a packed string from a 0-terminated character string
;The packed string overwrites the original string in memory
;The format of a packed string is described in Table A.2, p543
;Parameters -   R0 : address of the string

ST  R7, PAK_7

BACK    ADD R0, R0, R0

TRAP    x24

BRnp    BACK

LD  R7, PAK_7
RET

PAK_7   .BLKW   1


.END
```

Comment: Note: When I put the code into the simulator, the part where it's looping is a BRzp, and I don't know where that branch is coming from, or why it's there, I don't use a BRzp anywhere in my code.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! The issue was that I wasn't setting the flags to 0 when needed. (for anyone who was interested.)